# How do I determine no of non empty folders within each directory?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to simply trying to determine how many non empty folders are present in each of the base directories & ignore any file directly in the root directory.

To explain it better, here's the tree structure

```
❯ tree $HOME/count
/home/xd003/count
├── Random file in root to be ignored.mp4
├── base_folder1
│   ├── Empty folder to be ignored
│   └── Folder 1
│       └── file.mp4
└── base_folder2
    ├── Folder 1
    │   └── file.mp4
    └── Folder 2
        └── file.mp4
```

The 1st file needs to be ignored as it's directly in root. `base_folder1` has only 1 non empty folder ('Folder1') while `base_folder2` has 2 non empty folders ('Folder 1' & 'Folder 2')

Here's my bash script to determine the same.

```
foldercount() {
cd $HOME/count
for dir in *; do
        local name="${dir}"
        [[ -f ${name} ]] && continue #skip the files in root
        local folders total_folders top=0
        mapfile -t folders <<< "$(find "${name}" -type f -printf "%h\n" | sort -uV)"
        total_folders="${#folders[@]}"
        if [[ -z ${folders} ]]; then
            continue #skip empty folders
        elif [[ "${total_folders}" -ge 1 ]]; then
            echo "More than 1 non empty folders are detected"
        else
            echo "Only 1 non empty folder is detected"
        fi
done
}

foldercount
```

The issue is that it prints more than 1 non empty folder is detected for both of the base folders. The else condition simply doesn't gets executed. Ideally the else condition should get executed for `base_folder1`

PS: I need to fix the issue in my current script, I can't use a alternative solution as this is a small portion of a large script.

Comment: The operator `-ge` is for `greater than or equal to`. You may want to say: `elif [[ "$total_folders" -gt 1 ]]` or `elif (( $total_folders > 1 ))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments

The operator -ge is for greater than or equal to. Using the correct operator as shown below fixes the issue -

```
elif [[ "$total_folders" -gt 1 ]]
 or
elif (( $total_folders > 1 ))
```

Comment: Maybe just cosmetics, but IMHO the second variant would be more commonly written as `elif (( total_folders > 1 ))`. Of course the `$` in front does not harm. In the first variant, I would drop the unnecessary quotes and write `elif [[ $total_folders -gt 1 ]]`.